# Guidance / Advice on unlocking In-App Purchases

Tags: objective-c, app-store, in-app-purchase

I am looking for some advice / guide on the best way to unlock content from in-app purchases.

I have a list of 100 words. I have the broken into 25 units. The first unit of 25 is free and the remaining 3 units can be unlocked after you purchase them from an in-app purchase. No content will be downloaded.

All 100 words are currently stored in an array.

After the purchaser buys a unit, I want that specific segment to become available.

So if they buy unit 3, then the word list should include units 1 and 3.

What is the best way to implement this? Should I use 4 different `NSArrays` for the word sets? And then just load a master `NSArray` with the purchased words?

Answer (score 1):

For the bare minimum you could use four `NSArray`s and then add them to an `NSMutableArray` as they are purchased. And use `NSUserDefaults` to store a boolean for each possible purchase.

Comment: That's kinda how I have started, but it seems cumbersome to create 4 arrays. If I wanted to add 100 more words I would need 4 additional arrays... and so on. Just seems like a waste of memory.

Comment: Well I mean its bare minimum. If you're going to be adding words in the future you need to create a better method such as loading from a plist or Core Data.

Comment: If you're just looking for the best way then the question is FAR too broad.

Comment: +1. There is no pattern for such a broad question. One may like the game/level analogy. One other may prefer downloadable content. One other may implement additional content as database units, etc.

Comment: Not really broad. If you were in my shoes, how would you proceed with unlocking different sets of words? Would you have a giant list or multiple arrays?

Comment: I was thinking of using NSSet for a list of the words. But I was unsure if that is what NSSet is used for.

Comment: I'd have an array of words for each set, and an array of sets. The array of words would be loaded from plists in a loop. plists would include identifiers that could be compared with an NSUserDefaults store for ownership.

Comment: NSSet would work fine as well, its just an unordered array that is only allowed one instance of each object.

Comment: With NSSet, you must have separate sets. Since there is no order, once merged, you can't distinguish purchased content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know wether or not I understand your question correctly.

Maybe you could put everything into one big array and have a `max_available_index`. Each purchase increments this index. The user is never allowed to access items beyond this maximum index.

If your unit size is 25, then buying 3 units increments the `max_available_index` by 75.

Comment: @JasonBourne Does this answer your question? (I am not sure I understood what you wanted).

Comment: Mmmm not so much. I have seen plenty of tutorials on implementing that in-app store system, but never anything on what to do once the item is purchased.

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: More of a 'Best Practice' example or any tutorials on what to do AFTER the puchase has been made. The actual 'unlocking' of content.

Comment: Well, IMHO, the best way would be to make the purchased content downloadable. But you could also make the content readily available on the device and limiting what you show to the actual purchased content. One way to do this is by having the items sorted and unlocking them by indexes just as levels are unlocked in a game. In a game, you unlock levels by playing. In your app, you unlock word sets by paying.